# Why using the below nested jquery in rails give me error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to run the below nested query in rails 2.3.5 application but give me syntax error. Please help.

```
Student.find_by_sql(:conditions => [SELECT id,sibling_id,roll_num,first_name,fathername FROM
students WHERE sibling_id=?,
(select sibling_id from students where id=?,1)])
```

Following is the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in
>   your SQL synt ax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right  syntax to use near
>   '`students`.`conditions` IN ('select id,sibling_id,roll_num,
>   first_name,fathername' at line 1: `students`.`conditions` IN ('select
>   id,sibling
>   _id,roll_num,first_name,fathername from students where sibling_id = ?, (select s ibling_id from students where id = ?, 1)')
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_rec
>   ord/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `log'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_rec
>   ord/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:323:in`execute'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_rec
>   ord/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:608:in `select'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_rec
>   ord/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in`
>   select_all_without
>   _query_cache'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_rec
>   ord/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:62:in `select_all'
>           from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_rec
>   ord/base.rb:661:in`find_by_sql'
>           from (irb):1

Comment: If you are looking for help understanding an error, it would be very helpful if you would provide the specific text of the error in addition to the code that generates the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to quote the string to be used for the SQL query. When quoted it should look like:

```
Student.find_by_sql(:conditions => ["SELECT id,sibling_id,roll_num,first_name,fathername FROM 
students WHERE sibling_id=?,
(select sibling_id from students where id=?",1)])
```